# how does ImageIcon() of jython works in sikuli?

Tags: image, jython, sikuli

This is my code :-

```
from javax.swing import ImageIcon
from javax.swing import JFrame
from javax.swing import JPanel
from javax.swing import JLabel

class Example(JFrame):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        panel = JPanel()
        panel.setLayout(None)
        self.getContentPane().add(panel)


        image = ImageIcon("nmsirmmLoadi.png")
        t = JLabel(image)
        t.setBounds(20, 20, image.getIconWidth(), image.getIconHeight())
        panel.add(t)

        self.setTitle("Absolute")
        self.setSize(350, 300)
        self.setLocationRelativeTo(None)
        self.setVisible(True)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Example()
```

Here I am trying to create a GUI which will show an image.  This GUI is for a sikuli program and I have used jython.  So typed this code expecting that it would show the image which I have added, but the the GUI was blank, it didn't show the image. I am using sikuli r930 in windows 7.  Could someone help me out with this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is very simple. *ImageIcon* requires absolute path, not relative. Assuming your image is located in *d:\sikuli*, inititalization of variable *image* should look like this:

```
image = ImageIcon("d:\\sikuli\\nmsirmmLoadi.png")
```